# Landscape And Portrait Mode Layout Problems

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an Android application and having troubles with layouts.

I had created **layout-large** and **layout-large-land** folders to change landscape layout and portrait layout; but i have a strange problem.

If i had started application in portrait mode and rotated to landscape mode; application didn't change layout so user see portrait mode layout.
But if i had started application in landscape layout mode and rotated to portrait mode; application didn't change layout so user see landscape mode layout.

Both times if reopen that window, current orientation mode applied to screen.

There is no `android:orientation` attribute on layouts.

Comment: What is the value of android:screenOrientation="" in Manifest.xml for Activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you don't have [`android:configChanges="orientation"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) set in your AndroidManifest for that Activity (which avoids recreating the Activity on orientation change and therefore will not re-read your config specific layouts).

Comment: there was android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" attribute  at every activity. i don't know it affects this :)

Comment: yes, this means that your code will handle both orientation changes and changes in the keyboard accessibility (in Activity.onConfigurationChanged). if you want the system to automatically restart the activity on orientation change (therefore re-reading your new configuration specific layouts) you will need to remove "orientation" from configChanges or remove configChanges altogether. please see the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config